# Extract a number from column which contains a string

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have a function, which returns a combination of strings (multiple values). I need to extract everything that is followed by char "DL:". But only that.

So before extraction:

```
**pck_import.GETdocnumber(XML_DATA)**
________________________________________
DL:2212200090001 Pr:8222046017
________________________________________
Obj:020220215541 DL:1099089729
________________________________________
DL:DST22017260
________________________________________
DL:22122000123964 Pr:8222062485
________________________________________
DL:22122000108599
________________________________________
Obj:0202200015539 DL:2100001688
```

In every case, i'll need the "number" after char "DL:". The "DL:" can be alone, can be at first place (between multiple values), also can be the last string. Also in some cases, the "DL:" value contains char, too.

So, output:

```
**OUTPUT**
______________
2212200090001
______________
1099089729
______________
DST22017260
______________
22122000123964
______________
22122000108599
______________
2100001688
```

I tried:

```
substr(pck_import.GETdocnumber(XML_DATA),
instr(pck_import.GETdocnumber(XML_DATA),
'DL:') + 3))
```

That returns "Pr:", too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with s as (
select 'DL:2212200090001 Pr:8222046017'  str from dual union all
select 'Obj:020220215541 DL:1099089729'  str from dual union all
select 'DL:DST22017260'                  str from dual union all
select 'DL:22122000123964 Pr:8222062485' str from dual union all
select 'DL:22122000108599'               str from dual union all
select 'Obj:0202200015539 DL:2100001688' str from dual)
select str, regexp_substr(str, 'DL:(\S+)', 1, 1, null, 1) rs
from s;

STR                             RS
------------------------------- -------------------------------
DL:2212200090001 Pr:8222046017  2212200090001
Obj:020220215541 DL:1099089729  1099089729
DL:DST22017260                  DST22017260
DL:22122000123964 Pr:8222062485 22122000123964
DL:22122000108599               22122000108599
Obj:0202200015539 DL:2100001688 2100001688

6 rows selected
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select
  3  '________________________________________
  4  DL:2212200090001 Pr:8222046017
  5  ________________________________________
  6  Obj:020220215541 DL:1099089729
  7  ________________________________________
  8  DL:DST22017260
  9  ________________________________________
 10  DL:22122000123964 Pr:8222062485
 11  ________________________________________
 12  DL:22122000108599
 13  ________________________________________
 14  Obj:0202200015539 DL:2100001688'
 15  from dual)
 16  --
```

Query:

```
 17  select replace(regexp_substr(col, 'DL:\w+', 1, level), 'DL:') result
 18  from test
 19  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, 'DL:');

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2212200090001
1099089729
DST22017260
22122000123964
22122000108599
2100001688

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

(note that query might need to be modified if you'll be dealing with more than a single row of data)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using regular expressions utilising a positive lookbehind and lookahead.

The regex `(?<=DL\:)\d*(?=\s)'` matches all digits between `DL:` until a  single whitespace character occurs.

You'd want to use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function for this (as you tagged this question with OracleSQL):

```sql
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_column,
                '(?<=DL\:)\d*(?=\s)') "DL field"
  FROM my_table;
```

If you want to match substrings like `DST22017260` as well, using `.` (any character) instead of `\d` would work: `(?<=DL\:).*(?=\s)`.

Comment: [Oracle's regular expression support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html) doesn't include lookahead/behind. But as the others answers show, you don't need it for this anyway.